# Unable to Access Add-ons Folder

Tags: module, php-errors

I have just installed EE 3.4.5 for a new site and have added two modules: Structure and Wygwam. When I try and go to the Add-ons folder to activate and manage them, I get the following error:

> No such property: 'assigned_modules' on
>   EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Legacy\Facade
>   ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Legacy/Facade.php:107

Has anyone else had this problem and if so, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in 3.4.5. the solution is [here](https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs/22819/Add-on-manager-cannot-see-add-ons). Click on the solution tab to see the necessary code change.

Comment: Ran into this same thing yesterday.

Comment: A patched version (3.4.6) was released today btw.